# PHP MongoDB profiling

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to get profiling with PHP MongoDB but getting this error, Please help me I am new with mongoDB.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\Database::setProfilingLevel()

my code is as below:

```
<?php
//requiring the php library 
require('vendor/autoload.php');
//calling client
$client = new MongoDB\Client;
$demodb = $client->demodb;


# 0 (off), 1 (queries > 100ms), and 2 (all queries)
$demodb->setProfilingLevel(2);

# …
# Some queries 
$users = $demodb->users;

$doc = $users->findOne(
    ['_id' => '1']
);    
$docx = $users->find(
    ['skill' => 'java']
);
# …

$response = $demodb->system->profile->find();
foreach ($response as $query) {
    print_r($query);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is self explanatory but if you take a look at the MongoDB\Database class [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/reference/class/MongoDBDatabase/), you'll see the class doesn't have that method.

However, you can set the profiling level [via the mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/#db.setProfilingLevel) to achieve what you want.

If you wish to do this from PHP, you could use the `command` method on the Database object:

`$demodb->command(array('profile' => 2));`

Additionally, `$response = $demodb->system->profile->find();` will not work because you have to select the "system.profile" collection. You need to do `$response = $demodb->selectCollection("system.profile")->find();` instead

Comment: thanks for your concern, but i don't understand the command solution and i realy want to do profiling with PHP. So plz guide me more if u can....

Comment: Did you read the docs for the command method? https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/reference/method/MongoDBDatabase-command/ It basically executes a command on the db as you would do from the mongo shell for example, setting the profiling level. Which part are you not clear on?

Comment: the PHP docs state that the method you were probably trying to call is akin to calling the command directly anyways http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.setprofilinglevel.php

Comment: ok...! I am understanding the situation now... i have check this http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.setprofilinglevel.php so many times but not focused on command(), now i am trying to... I am reading this    https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/tutorial/commands/ but confused about where to put the query for profiling in command method....

Comment: you need to clarify in your question what you're trying to achieve. I have assumed you wanted to understand how to set the profiling level on the DB, for which I have provided the answer - use the snippet in my answer instead of `$demodb = $client->demodb;`

Comment: as in http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.setprofilinglevel.php this $this->command(array('profile' => $level)); replace this MongoDB::setProfilingLevel ( int $level ). I have replaced this $demodb->setProfilingLevel(2); with this $demodb->command(array('profile' => 2)); but not working....

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"? do you get an error message? unexpected output?

Comment: @ExoticChimps now I am getting error on this line $response = $demodb->system->profile->find(); error#1: Undefined property: MongoDB\Collection::$profile error#2: Call to a member function find() on null

Comment: rest of the code is same just replace this line $demodb->setProfilingLevel(2); with this $demodb->command(array('profile' => 2)); and getting errors on this line $response = $demodb->system->profile->find();

Comment: that's a different issue to your question. you're calling find on a null object i.e. $demodb->system->profile is null probably because you're not selecting the collection correctly. you should do `$demodb->selectCollection('system.profile')` then call `find()` on that instead of `$demodb->system->profile`

Comment: you mean like this..? `$collection = $demodb->selectCollection('users', 'system.profile');

foreach ($collection->find() as $document) {
   print_r($document);
}`

Comment: no your database is "demodb" not "myapp_db". you already have an instance of the database in your code in the variable `$demodb". so you may as well just call `selectCollection` on `$demodb`. Reread the updated answer

Comment: Thanks alot...! now my code is `$demodb->command(array('profile' => 2)); $users = $demodb->users; $collection = $demodb->selectCollection('system.profile'); 
foreach ($collection->find() as $document) {
 var_dump($document); 
}` and I am getting an output trying to understand the output but problem is that `find()` is only working as null argument so it's finding all the documents and giving output about them all i cannot put any selection criteria in `find()`.

Comment: @IramChauhdri that's more general querying usage of the mongodb library. With a little reading of the docs/stack overflow you should be able to find what you want rather than us trying to write the entire code in the comments. I recommend you accept this answer as you're original issue is resolved and do some more reading

Comment: @IramChauhdri no problem, please use the green tick to accept the answer if you found what you were looking for